# Date new stock displayed wrong

Tags: stock, date, qty-increment

We load data from our supplier about the date when new stock will arrive.
The date is loaded like: 07-12-2016, which is 12 July 2016 and not 7 December 2016.

I use following code to load the date:

CODE:

```
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php $today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($_product->getData('delivery_eta')); $date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false); echo $date;?></p>
```

But this is displayed as 7 December 2016. How can I change this, so that the date is loaded correctly like 12 July 2016?

Comment: 07-12-2016 - this is 12 July, right? Please correct it in your post

Comment: @Neklo.com Sorry, you are right. I changed it.

Comment: The date shown without setting specific formatting will be formatted according to choosen locale. Change your locale to English (United States) and check the formatted date one more time. For example the date you've said is July isn't right in many countries in Europe. That's why you shouldn't override the locale-specific date for all stores if they're working on different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is new code.

```
$date = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'), 'MM-dd-yyyy');
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
    $date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false
);
echo $date;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does display the date of today. Not the date of the delivery_eta attribute.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, don't see any error in code and it works well for me. Just maybe your delivery_eta data contain also time (hours, minutes, seconds)?

Comment: No, my date just looks like this: 07-12-2016. But in my case it is displaying the date of today, not thet date of the delivery_eta.. How is that possible?

Comment: Tried it again and I still get the date of today. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you add "echo " at the beginning of first line and post result here?  or can you try to change line 3 to next  -  $new_date = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($pieces[1].".".$pieces[0].".".$pieces[2]));

Comment: Thanks, when I add echo at the beginning of the first line. I get the following result: "08-12-2016donderdag 14 juli 2016". I also tried to edit line 3, but that does not work.

Comment: Oh, God. Thanks for your partience. Finaly we've solved your problem with next short code. Hope this will work )  -   $date = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'), 'MM-dd-yyyy');
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
echo $date;

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your data on the fly, like this

```
$dateString = $_product->getData('delivery_eta');
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
$today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape(newDateString);
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
```

or, equivalently:

```
$dateString = $_product->getData('delivery_eta');
$newDateString = date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $dateString), 'd-m-Y');
$today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape(newDateString);
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! What will the best and fastest way? Equivalently?

Comment: first one is more correct from developer point of view

Comment: I tried your code, but that does not seem to work. I do not get any value.

Comment: oh, sorry, I've missed $ sign at line 4.  It should be $today = Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($newDateString);

Comment: Thanks! I tried the new code, but that also does not work. The date is not displayed.

Comment: righty ( sorry, seems some php core issue with default convertion function. see my new comment with more simple code, that I've rechecked on my server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p class="availability out-of-stock">
<?php 
    $deliveryDate = $_product->getData('delivery_eta'); 
    $today = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($deliveryDate)); 
    $date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false);
?>
<?php echo $date;?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that code, but that does not work.